# Error while trying to run SoapUI mock service as a windows service

Tags: soap, soapui

I have made a Mock Service using SoapUI and used the following command 
`"D:\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\mockservicerunner.bat" -m "IOrderService MockService" "D:\Direct Deliveries Soap UI\Mock-Service-soapui-project.xml"`

But this doesn't seem to work, I get the following errors in my logs

[image: Error Logs while running above command]

I found [this](http://www.aspnet4you.com/wcf/index.php/2013/03/22/soapui-mock-service-proxy/) but couldn't recreate what was done here......

Please shed some light on this topic.

I am trying to use the bundled `mockservicerunner.bat` to run the mock service as a windows service.

Comment: The summary & description of the question are not in sync. Is the real issue is to resolve `SLF4j` or with windows service? Please edit the question to correct it / make it clarify.

Comment: I edited the question accordingly...